# GCM chrome notifications not being received

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

I am developing a chrome extension to which I was pushing notifications so far successfully from my server. However, the notifications suddenly stopped working. I can see that my POST to `https://www.googleapis.com/gcm_for_chrome/v1/messages` is answered with a 204 so its not my server code.

I am sure I have not hit the 10k per day limit because I would be seeing a completely different code otherwise.

I have a few questions:

1. Is there a rate limit that I may be hitting?
2. Is it possible that I have spammed the google server too much and am being blocked?

Comment: Still having this issue?

Comment: @PaulR it fixed itself after a day or so. :(